# Emitted Error Event when Upload File in Adonisjs

Tags: javascript, event-handling, adonis.js

When I’m trying to upload the file using ali-oss but I find some error here and I don’t understand. That error like this:

```
events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\PROJECT\myapp\files\1\uploads\test.jpg'
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:115:12)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: you upload your file in tmp folder ?

Comment: yes! is that make problem?

Comment: yes because you not upload any file without tmp directory or public directory.